# Translation Golf XXVI - Le Mans

Tags: traducción, translation-golf

**Aaaand [Charlie](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12637/charlie) wins the race, blazing past the cheering spectators at [409 chars/answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23237/13628)!!

Congratulations!**

---

> *Instantly the Mercedes was airborne. A 3,000-pound metal projectile with a tank of flammable liquid was 15 feet off the ground, rocketing at about 150 mph toward a crowd of spectators, with Levegh still hunched over the wheel. The car hit an embankment and exploded, hurtling fiery chunks of metal into the gathered mass. What was at one moment the social high point of the year —a party accented by the clink of wine glasses and the bellowing of sports car engines— became something unimaginably horrific. Dozens lay prostrate and bleeding. Fire raged; the car's magnesium body, made of a material similar to that used in early camera flashes, melted quickly into a thik soup of white-hot metal. Panic ensued. Those who were able to get on their feet fled and into that wave of foot traffic, photographers covering the race aimed and snapped, freezing shocked faces in black-and-white celluloid.*
>
> <sub>(723 characters)</sub>

---

Welcome to a new edition of the game!
If this is your first time, there's some info for beginners at the end of this post.

The above is an excerpt from the prologue to [Go Like Hell](https://books.google.es/books?id=4ddp0G3z-y0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=es#v=onepage&q&f=false), a book about the rivalry between Henry Ford II and Enzo Ferrari, and the history of the Ford GT40, since its inception to its victory over Ferrari at Le Mans in 1966.

The proposed text talks about the [1955 Le Mans disaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1955_Le_Mans_disaster), a sad milestone in car racing which forced teams and sponsors alike to rethink the role of safety in motor sports.

---

The goal is to translate the given text to Spanish, using as few letters as possible, while keeping all the original text's meaning and concepts more or less intact.

My own non-golfed translation follows:

> Instantáneamente el Mercedes saltó por los aires. Un proyectil de metal de 1350 kilos con un tanque de líquido inflamable iba a 5 metros del suelo, como un cohete a unos 240 km/h hacia una multitud de espectadores, con Levegh todavía aferrándose al volante. El coche dio contra un terraplén y explotó, lanzando fieros trozos de metal hacia la masa reunida. Lo que un momento antes era el mayor evento social del año —una fiesta adornada con el tintineo de vasos de vino y el bramido de los motores de los coches de carreras— se convirtió en algo inimaginablemente horrorífico. Docenas estaban postrados y sangrando. El fuego se extendía; el cuerpo de magnesio del coche, hecho de un material similar a lo que usaban los flashes de las cámaras antiguas, se fundió rápidamente en una sopa de metal candente. Cundió el pánico. Los que podían mantenerse en pie huyeron y en medio de esa ola de tráfico a pie, los fotógrafos que cubrían la carrera apuntaban y disparaban, congelando en celuloide blanco y negro las caras en choque.
>  
>  <sub>(823 characters)</sub>

---

- Rules: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)
- Letter counter: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

You may want to check past [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf) questions to get a feel of the game dynamics and the kind of answers expected.

Want to share translation ideas, ask for clarifications or just tease other contesters? Join us in [Translation-Golf!](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66153/translation-golf), our game-specific chat room, or in [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia), Spanish.SE's official chat room!

Have fun!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### <strike>471 435</strike> 409 caracteres

> Un Mercedes de 1360 [kilos](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Mh281FW), metal y combustible con Levegh aún al volante, [de choz](http://dle.rae.es/?id=910Laee) cual bala a 15 pies del suelo, a 240 [km](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MhG3UJg)/[h](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KdzJ1hu), hacia el público, al que arrojó metal en ascuas al explotar contra tierra. El [clímax](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9T6JVX7) social del año ([sonorizado](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YMoT2UO) con los [brindis](http://dle.rae.es/?id=66ukfhJ) y el ruido de los motores) mutó en horror. Muchos yacían sangrando. Incendios. La carrocería de magnesio, cual *[flash](http://dle.rae.es/?id=I3gkUNG)* de vieja cámara, fue sopa densa de metal [al rojo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WcdRRD4#A0r1RaL). Pánico. La [prensa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=U2brOEw) allí tomó fotos en película monocroma de las caras en *[shock](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XmEiKOR)* de los que huían a pie.

Explicaciones:

- Se han convertido las cantidades al sistema internacional cuando la unidad de medida convertida era más corta que la original.
- Si el Mercedes iba "cual bala a 15 pies del suelo" es que iba volando, no es necesario especificarlo.
- "Sonorizar" significa "ambientar una escena, un programa, etc., mediante los sonidos adecuados".
- Las copas de vino solo hacen ruido cuando se chocan para brindar.
- La "prensa" en su acepción 4 es el "conjunto de personas dedicadas al periodismo", y eso incluye a los fotógrafos que estaban tomando fotos para la prensa.
- "La prensa [que estaba] allí [presente]"...

Comment: @walen muy bien, cambio los símbolos dado que es tu pregunta y es tu interpretación de un vacío legal. Yo entiendo que las abreviaturas y los símbolos son cosas diferentes que se deben tratar diferente: el diccionario no dice "la abreviatura de señor es sr.", pero sí dice que el símbolo del metro es "m", por eso lo consideraba adecuado. Podemos tratar este tema en el chat (o en Meta) para próximas preguntas, y actualizar las reglas con lo que se decida.

Comment: @walen que los símbolos no son palabras, en eso estamos de acuerdo. Yo solo decía que los símbolos no son abreviaturas y la regla solo habla sobre estas, de ahí el vacío. Pero si crees que no hay tal vacío, lo recomendable en todo caso será decir en la regla "abreviaturas, símbolos y demás que no aparezcan como entradas en el diccionario" o algo así.

Comment: El que no quería usar cifras en los números xD. Para mi los símbolos son similares a las abreviaturas, creo que podría aplicarse la misma norma. En cualquier caso estaría bien debatirlo y añadir en las reglas lo que se decida, mientras tanto para el juego actual el criterio de @walen es la ley.

Comment: @blonfu yo no quería, pero si se ha acordado que se pueden usar, ¿por qué no voy a hacerlo yo también? :-D

Comment: No lo decía por los números de este TG ya que el original los usa también sino por tu defensa ahora de los símbolos

Answer (score 4):

#### <s>522 475 468</s> 433 caracteres

> De golpe el Mercedes volaba a 15 pies hacia la grada a 150 mph, Levegh
> aún sobre el volante. Una bala de 3000 libras llena de gasolina chocó
> con un dique y explotó lanzando metralla contra la gente. La fiesta
> culmen del año, avivada por el tintín de copas de vino y el rugir de
> los motores, trocó en atrocidad. Gente sangrando en el suelo. Creció
> el fuego; el auto de magnesio, como los viejos flashes, se licuó veloz
> en un puré de metal candente. Pánico. Fotógrafos del acto retrataron
> en blanco y negro las caras turbadas de quienes huían a pie.

- Pongo *volaba* junto a *15 pies* para que se sobrentienda que son 15 pies de altura
- **Grada**: Público que ocupa la grada.

Answer (score 3):

#### 620 characters

El Meche voló de pronto. Un obús metálico de 3000 libras con un tanque de fluido inflamable levantó 15 pies del piso, disparado como a 150 mph contra el público, con Levegh aún al volante. El coche cayó en un talud y detonó, echando cachos de metal ígneo a los que estaban ahí. Lo que fue ápice social del año (fiesta marcada por tintineos de copas de vino y motores de coche deportivo rugiendo) devino pandemonio.
Docenas estaban tirados sangrando. El fuego ardía. La lámina de magnesio del coche, de material como de flashes de cámara vieja, se fundió en una densa sopa de metal al blanco. Empezó el pánico. Los que podían pararse huyeron, y los fotógrafos que cubrían la carrera apuntaron a esa ola peatonal, disparando, fijando caras de susto en celuloide blanco y negro.

Comment: Mejor el número de caracteres arriba, así aparece en los feeds del chat. Por cierto ¿se llama Meche a los Mercedes? El nombre Mercedes en personas sí que se acorta a Merche pero sin r y para un coche no lo había visto nunca

Comment: Había comentado que no entendía la expresión "los que podían pararse huyeron", pero acabo de ver que en América "pararse" significa "ponerse en pie". :-)

Comment: @walen ¡grácias por la edición!

Comment: @blonfu así es, uso modismos mexicanos en mi versión.

Comment: @Charlie ref. el comentario anterior